# Swift iOS -Adding second UIWindow doesn't appear

Tags: ios, swift, uiwindow

I have a second UIWindow I'm adding to my app. When I add it the window briefly shows and then suddenly disappears. It might show for  a tenth of a second then poof it's gone. Where am I going wrong at?

```
class AddSecondWindowClass: NSObject {

    let redVC = RedController()
    var window: UIWindow?

    func showSecondWindow() {

        let navVC = UINavigationController(rootViewController: redVC)
        navVC.navigationBar.isHidden = true
        window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
        window?.backgroundColor = .white
        window?.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar
        window?.rootViewController = navVC
        window?.isHidden = false
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
}

class RedController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = .red
    }

    deinit {
        print("RedVC -DEINIT")
    }
}
```

A different class with a button that shows the window

```
@IBAction func triggerSecondWindowButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let addSecondWindowClass = AddSecondWindowClass()
    addSecondWindowClass.showSecondWindow()
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are not keeping the `AddSecondWindowClass` object around.

You create a variable in the `triggerSecondWindowButton(sender:)` method, but as soon as the function completes, `addSecondWindowClass` has no more references to it and is soon destroyed. When this object is destroyed, your window you added has no more references so is also destroyed.

To solve this, you just have to keep a reference to the `AddSecondWindowClass` somewhere it will be kept around for as long as you want the window to be visible. (Perhaps as a property or ivar in the class `triggerSecondWindowButton(sender:)` is in).

Comment: You rule! Thank you very much 

Comment: quick question, I'm going to add an animation to the AddSecondWindowClass and eventually dismiss it. Will adding that property somehow cause a retain cycle? Should I declare it as weak? weak var addSecondWindowClass: AddSecondWindowClass? and then initialize it in viewDidLoad

Comment: now that I think about they don't reference each other so they shouldn't

Comment: If you declare it as weak, then it would not be retained and you would have the same issue as before. However, if AddSecondWindowClass has a reference to the object that created it, that reference should be weak to avoid a retain cycle.

Comment: Yeah AddSecondWidndowClass doesn’t have a reference to the class with the button. Thanks for the info and enjoy your evening